# tkinter window not displaying

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python and trying to develop a webcrawler app.  Currently, I don't get any error messages, however the gui doesn't display when the code is run.  Any help is appreciated.

I've searched for similar issues on stackoverflow but could find anything that matched.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

LARGE_FONT=("Helvetica",12)

class MMA_fighters(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self,"Mixed Martial Arts Fighters")

        container =tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top",fill="both",expand="true")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

        self.frames={ }

        for F in (StartPage,MainPage):

            frame=F(container,self)
            self.frames[F]=frame
            frame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):
        frame=self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label=ttk.Label(self,text="Mixed Martial Arts Fighters", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        label=ttk.Label(self,text="Select 'Continue' for more information on your favorite MMA fighter", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button1=ttk.Button(self,text="Continue",command=lambda :controller.show_frame(MainPage))
        button1.pack()
        button2=ttk.Button(self,text="Exit",command=quit())
        button2.pack()


class MainPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label=ttk.Label(self,text="Fighter",font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

app=MMA_fighters()
app.mainloop()
```

The expected result is the window to appear with exit and continue items progressing to the second page.  The actual result is the window does not appear.

Comment: first select code in question and use button `{}` to format it correctly.

Comment: The `command=quit()` in the creation of `button2` is immediately closing the window.  You just want `command=quit`, to reference the function without calling it yet.

Answer (score 0):

`command=` expects function's name without `()` - so called "callback" - and when you press button then `mainloop` will get this name and use `()` to run it.

But you have `command=quit()` so it executes `quit()` at start and exit program.

You need

```
command=quit
```

---

You could use `app.destroy` instead of `quit` to inform window that you want to end program and it should close window before it ends program.